# Recursively going through a model

Tags: django, python-3.x, tail-recursion

I have a model like so:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    def lastfolder(self):
        try:
            return self.folder_set.all().order_by('-created_at')[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def lastdrive(self):
        try:
            return self.drive_set.all().order_by('-created_at')[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def lastfile(self):
        try:
            return self.drive_set.all().order_by('-created_at')[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {'slug' : self.slug}
        return reverse('', kwargs=kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Drive(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    cover_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=f'media/{user_path}', default="media/drive.png")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {'slug' : self.slug}
        return reverse('', kwargs=kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['owner', 'name']]
        ordering = ('name',)

class Folder(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    drive = models.ForeignKey('Drive', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    cover_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=f'media/{user_path}', default="media/folder-white.png")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    path = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {'slug' : self.slug}
        return reverse('', kwargs=kwargs)

    def get_path(self):
        yield self.name
        try:
            yield from get_path(self.parent)
        except:
            pass

    def complete_get_path(self):
        text = []
        for i in self.get_path():
            text.append(i)
        text.reverse()
        return "/".join(text)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.path = self.complete_get_path()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['parent', 'name']]
        ordering = ('name',)
```

If I create a `Folder` instance with a `name` Programming and another `Folder` instance with a `name` Python and `parent` with reference to Programming, it is supposed to populate the `path` field for Programming with "Programming" and Python with "Programming/Python". Unfortunately, it does not work

My emphasis is on the `Folder` model and the methods: `get_path`, `complete_get_path`, and `save`. 
After saving the model, and checking the `path` field in the admin, it just shows only the `name` attribute not return the actual generated path of the folder.

How do I go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `get_path` isn't defined and the blanket try/except is eating your error. Your method should be:

```
def get_path(self):
    yield self.name
    yield from self.parent.get_path()
```

Here's a slight optimization. If you yield the parent's path's first, you don't have to reverse the list of folder names and then can simply join it at the end.

```
def get_path(self):
    yield from self.parent.get_path()
    yield self.name

def complete_get_path(self):
    return "/".join(self.get_path())
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `get_path` return a `NoneType` error when the method is performed on a `Folder` instance with no `parent`. So I wrapped the `yield from self.parent.get_path()` in a  `try/except` block and it worked.
Thanks a million.

Comment: You should do `if self.parent: yield from self.parent.get_path()`. When possible try to use if/else conditions rather than try/except